# Mandar datos de Firebase a un Fragment Android Studio

Tags: firebase, android-fragment, navigationview

necesito ayuda para mostrar datos que tengo almacenados en una base de datos de Firebase en un fragment de Navigation Drawer.

Al momento de iniciar sesión carga un Navigation Drawer con varios fragments.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y quiero que al momento de iniciar sesión la etiqueta que dice "email@email" cambie de texto por un dato que tengo almacenado en Firebase, pero al pasar a este fragment la aplicación se cierra.

Aquí esta el código del Activity Main, no se realmente si debe ir ahí o ¿en cual fragment debería ir?

```
public class Main extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;

    private TextView mEmail;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_slideshow,
                R.id.nav_tools, R.id.nav_share, R.id.nav_send)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);

        mEmail = findViewById(R.id.txtemailus);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {

                if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {

                    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
                    mDatabase.child(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            mEmail.setText(String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("Email").getValue()));
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
                }
                else {

                     startActivity(new Intent(Main.this, Login.class));
                     finish();
                    /**
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), PlanA.class);
                    getActivity().startActivity(intent);
                    getActivity().finish();*/
                }
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){

        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setMessage(R.string.close)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.y, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        Main.this.finish();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.n, null)
                .show();
    }
}
```

El error que me marca el Logcat es:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
    at com.innovapp.ahorrochallenge.Main$1$1.onDataChange(Main.java:74)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.0.0:75)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.0.0:63)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.0.0:55)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
```

Comment: cual es el error que te tira el logcat cuando se cierra ?

Comment: Describe el error que te genera cuando abres la app, y que tipo de excepción

Comment: Ya añadí el error que me marca en el Logcat, saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución es agregar estas lineas de código:

```
View hView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
tEmail = hView.findViewById(R.id.txtemailus)
```

Entonces quedaría así:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

    mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_slideshow,
            R.id.nav_tools, R.id.nav_share, R.id.nav_send)
            .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
            .build();
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);

    View hView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);

    tEmail = hView.findViewById(R.id.txtemailus);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {

            if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {

                mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
                mDatabase.child(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        mEmail = (String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("Email").getValue()));
                        tEmail.setText(mEmail);

                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }
            else {

                 startActivity(new Intent(Main.this, Login.class));
                 finish();
            }
        }
    };
}
```